# Links to User Profiles, Routing, from All_Users Page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Trying to make my all_users page render a list of all users that have accounts - and then each list item would be a link to that user's profile page. I have the page rendering the usernames correctly, but they're not pointing to their user pages. Their user pages should be /user/username, but the links are pointing to /username, which gives an error, obviously. I really, really, really appreciate the help. Stack Overflow has been truly incredible.

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
     attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
     has_many :items

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  def to_param
    username
  end

end
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
  end
  def index
@user = User.find(:all)
  end
end
```

All_Users View:

```
<div class="well">
  <h1>All users</h1>

  <% @user.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to user.username, public_profile_path(user.username) %><br/>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Routes:

```
Scratch::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :items

  devise_for :users
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
  match '/users', :to => 'users#index', :as => "all_users", :via => "get"
  match ':username' => 'users#show', via: :get, as: :public_profile

  root :to => 'static_pages#home'
  get "about" => "static_pages#about"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match '/username/:name' => 'users#show', via: :get, as: :public_profile
```

Comment: match '/users/:username' => 'users#show', via: :get, as: :public_profile

I did that, is that okay too?

Comment: no you have defined the same helper twice,  they should be different.  Try :show_public_profile

Answer (score 1):

I tend to make a new controller so that I dont end up overriding devise.

Something like Admin::Users then in there I just do the basic scaffold then map the vars in that controller to the Devise user model.

That way I can restyle the devise views for front end use and the admin views for back end use.